# RDSH Network Printer Mapping via Group Policy / Power Shell

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, powershell, group-policy, network-printer

Got a huge hurdle currently that I need to try and overcome.

I have successfully mapped print server defined printers via GPO and all is well on the client side machines.

However, i am having issues with RDCs and mapping printers from a print server using a local name like above

The process i have currently is this.

- User logs onto windows 10 machine.
- Group policy wipes any One note printers, shared and IP printers, maps printers using a local name via TCP/IP that i have set within the GPO. This is all dependent on the security group that the user is in to what printer they receive.
- Another group policy toggles the Windows 10 "Let windows manage my default printer"
- A final group policy sets the default printer based on the users location.

This is all well and good. Inefficient but functional.

Here is the overall layout for the Printer within the GPO. 
Note, this is on the User configuration not PC. I want printers to follow the users around and not be bound to PCs due to hotdesking.

[image]

The issue i now face is trying to get these "Local Named" printers into a RDC that the user logs into.

The current implementation is via powershell.
When a user logs in, they are supposed to have the same printers mapped to them as outlined by the GPO above.

However, these do not transfer from the Local GPO to the RDC/RDSH.

I understand now that this is a limitation that i was not expecting.

Is there a way to map the exact same network printers that the user has on their local machine across to their profile on the RDC/RDSH every time they log in?

I have been stuck on this for a couple of days now and have resorted to powershell scripting to see if i can crowbar in a solution.

I just want to make sure im heading down the right path and havent avoided anything stupid

I will be happy to clarify anything required